# Why am I earning documentation privileges?

Tags: bug, documentation, privileges

In the past day I've earned two privileges for a feature that doesn't exist any more:

- Documentation Review:
  [image: Documentation Review]
- Documentation Comments:
  [image: Documentation Comments]

Both of these link to help documentation which is still active.

If documentation is discontinued, the announcements of the privileges should no longer occur.

Comment: It's an undocumented feature....sorry bad joke.

Comment: Documentation had a rough life.  It's hard for it to RIP.

Comment: Return of the Living Documentation

Comment: Ha, this is what happens when I think "we're just about ready to remove all of its code anyway, so that'll fix itself" and then "just about ready" turns into three months because of reasons.

Comment: @AdamLear [maybe this helps](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/931562903773368320). :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Welcome to my personal hell. :)